# How do I write a function to count the characters in a string?

Tags: r, function, character

I'm working a practice exercise for a class, and I've reached an impasse. The instructions state:

> Write a function that takes a string of text and counts the number of characters. The function should return "There are xx characters in that string."

This is what I have thus far:

```
w <- "I hope everyone has a good weekend"


answer <- function (nchar) {
  statement <- paste("There are", nchar, "characters in that string")
}
```

I've tried plugging "w" into the function to see if it works, but I didn't get any results. Please bear in mind that I'm new to R.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the function

> nchar()

with your function input

Look at the following:

> w <- "I hope everyone has a good weekend"
>
> answer <- function (myInputString) {   statement <- paste("There are",
> nchar(myInputString),   "characters in that string")
> return(statement) }

Note that you also missed to add return at the end of your function, to specify what the output should be.

Good luck with you journey into coding ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm only a few weeks into it, so there's plenty to learn. But I do genuinely want to get the hang of it. It's quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Just for a bit of fun - and for you to try to work out what is going on - here are some alternative functions that give the same answer as the built-in `nchar` but don't actually use it...

This one splits it into a list of single characters, converts it to a vector, and returns the length...

```
nchar1 <- function(s) length(unlist(str_split(s, "")))
```

This one converts it into RAW format (a vector of the byte values that are used to encode the string) and returns the length...

```
nchar2 <- function(s) length(charToRaw(s))
```

This one uses a `while` loop to see at which point the substring function `substr` returns an empty string...

```
nchar3 <- function(s){
  i <- 0
  while(substr(s, i+1, i+2) != ""){
    i <- i+1
    }
  return(i)
}
```

This one uses a similar approach to count how many times we can remove the first character before getting to an empty string...

```
nchar4 <- function(s){
  i <- 0
  while(s != ""){
    s <- sub(".", "", s)
    i <- i + 1
  }
  return(i)
}
```

This one might make your head hurt a bit. It uses a similar technique to the last one but uses `Recall` to call itself until it gets to the point (a blank string) at which it returns an answer.

```
nchar5 <- function(s, n = 0){
  if(s == "") {
    return(n)
  } else {
    Recall(sub(".", "", s), n + 1)
  }
}

nchar1("Good luck!")
[1] 10
nchar2("Good luck!")
[1] 10
nchar3("Good luck!")
[1] 10
nchar4("Good luck!")
[1] 10
nchar5("Good luck!")
[1] 10
```

Comment: I can't begin to tell you how helpful this is. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`nchar` is your function to count the number of characters in a string. If you don't want to count the whitespace you could use `gsub` to remove them from your string and count again the characters. You could use the following code:

```r
w <- "I hope everyone has a good weekend"

answer <- function (x) { 
  statement <- paste("There are", nchar(x), "characters in that string")
  statement
}
answer(w)
#> [1] "There are 34 characters in that string"

answer2 <- function (x) { 
  statement <- paste("There are", nchar(gsub(" ", "",x))
, "characters in that string")
  statement
}
answer2(w)
#> [1] "There are 28 characters in that string"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>